# SQL query cannot use NOT LIKE to get results

Tags: sql, select, count, where-clause, redash

I am starting out in SQL and am trying to do a query that will select all event names that are unique and do not have 'TODAY-XXXXXXXX' in the value for the event_name column. I have a query that works fine for getting the unique values from the table, but I cannot get the NOT LIKE to work well.

For example, I was to remove all items that have this as their name TODAY-20191021 the data at the end can change but all have the TODAY in front of the date

This is the query that is working fine

```
SELECT DISTINCT event_name, COUNT(*)
FROM events 
GROUP BY event_name
Having COUNT(*) > 100.
```

But when I try to add the where clause it fails with this error

> Error running query: column "TODAY-%" does not exist LINE 3: WHERE event_name NOT LIKE "TODAY-%" ^

This is what I have so far

```
SELECT DISTINCT event_name, COUNT(*)
FROM events 
WHERE event_name NOT LIKE "TODAY%"
GROUP BY event_name
Having COUNT(*) > 100.
```

Comment: Use single quotes instead of double quotes: `WHERE event_name NOT LIKE 'TODAY%'`

Comment: Thank you that worked can you put this as an answer and I will mark it as the correct choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
WHERE event_name NOT LIKE "TODAY%"
```

Because you use double quotes, the database considers this string as an identifier (here, a column name). Instead, you want to use single quotes, that stand for literal strings:

```
WHERE event_name NOT LIKE 'TODAY%'
```